# Remove all chars from a string except "a","b","c","d"

Tags: lua, gsub, lua-patterns

I have a string where I want to replace all chars and digits with `""`, except chars `a`,`b`,`c`, `d`.

Instead of having to write multiple lines of long code like in the example below, is there some other way to write this more efficient?

```
myString:gsub("[%(%)%.%%%+%-%*%?%[%]%^%$%,]", "") --special chars
... --same for chars
... --same for digits
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use caret symbol `^`
That is, `[^abcd]`

Caret symbol negates your set.

E.g., you can read it more carefully [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=string.find).